# Polymer 2.0 splash screen

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

How in the polymer 2.0 do the splash screen when app is loading?
I am waiting a 4 seconds for first loading.

I dont understand when elements is loaded.

Comment: what do you mean? u want to have a splash screen? btw. 4 seconds seems way longer then it should be...

Answer (score 0):

You can load a splash screen the same way [Topeka](https://polymer-topeka.appspot.com/) (though built on Polymer 0.5) does with [css](https://github.com/Polymer/topeka/blob/master/theme.css#L20).